# How do I use C++ written code in Swift via Interoperability

Tags: c++, swift, interop

I'm using this guides
(first one I described below step by step)
https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/main/docs/CppInteroperability/GettingStartedWithC%2B%2BInterop.md

https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2023/10172/

https://www.swift.org/documentation/cxx-interop/project-build-setup/#mixing-swift-and-c-using-xcode

And I can't figure out how to properly set my project to use c++ functions, classes with methods in swift. Can someone please explain it to me?

So, I create Xcode project (Comman Line Tool), make new target (library), select (STL and dynamic) and I get new folder with 3 files. After that I create `modulemap` and do all necessary build settings.

Swift guide says:

> This should now allow your to import your C++ Module into any `.swift` file.

But when I write `import CxxTest` it throws:

> No such module 'CxxTest'

It doesn't matter if I check C++/Objective-C++ in project settings (as it was in 2nd guide)

Comment: Hey Keril! What Swift version are you using? This is a pretty new feature, perhaps you just don't have a compiler version that has it, yet?

Comment: @Alexander, I'm using swift 5.10 and I'm on XCode 15.3. The interesting thing, that this project [Mix Swift and C++](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/mixinglanguagesinanxcodeproject) is working, but for me as a newcomer it looks a bit difficult to understand.

Comment: Hmmm I'm not sure how to debug this. The Swift forums might be a good place to ask this, because it has a lot of people there on the cutting-edge of this